# javaScript text.replace only replaces one of the words I wanted replaced

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I was wondering why my

```
    var newText = text.replace("like", "love");
```

followed by

```
    var newText = text.replace("pie", "tie food");
```

only replaces "pie" with    "tie food" and not "like" with "love"
So this is what I have:

```
    <textarea id="text3" type="text" name="paragraph_text" style="height:500px; width: 1315px" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
  function replace(){
    var text = document.getElementById("text3").value;
    var newText = text.replace("like", "love");
    var newText = text.replace("pie", "tie food");
    document.getElementById("text3").value = newText;
  }
</script>
```

And as I said, it only replaces "pie" with "tie food" not "like" with "love."

So this is what the text box says:

```
    I like eating pie
```

And after clicking the "replace" button, I want it to say

```
    I love eating tie food
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why do you redeclare `newText`?

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript - `.replace` returns a _new_ string. So you do two replacement on the same text and store only one of the results.

Comment: Please, at least try to solve your issue by yourself : If you have used the javascript debugger, you would have found that the second `replace` statement don't apply to the right variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chain the replaces, because [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string:

> The **`replace()`** method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

```js
var text = 'I like eating pie',
    newText = text.replace("like", "love").replace("pie", "tie food");

console.log(newText);
```

Comment: Could you at least offer some explanation?

Comment: @AndrewL., no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution, where `map` is a mapping object of replaces (every key will be replaced with the value, can be extended simply)

```
var map = {pie: 'tie food', like: 'love'}     
var reg = new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join('|'), 'gi')

var text = 'I like eating pie'

var newText = text.replace(reg, function(matched) {
  return map[matched];
})
```